# How handle EditText Change Listener in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener

Imagine I have 5 EditText and I need to to populate values when one edittext value is changed. The values are interdependent. I am using the following logic to achieve that.

```
//Finding which edit text is originating values 

for(int i=0;i<mEditTextIds.length;i++){ 
        txt[i]=(EditText) findViewById(mEditTextIds[i]);
        txt[i].setOnTouchListener(new EditTextTouchLisner());
        txt[i].setId(i);
}


//Enable that Edittext's TextChangeListner and disabling all other Edittext's TextChangeListner ..

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    for(int i=0;i<mTableRowIds.length;i++){
        if(i!=v.getId()){
            txt[i].addTextChangedListener(null);
        }       
    }
    txt[v.getId()].addTextChangedListener(new TextChangedListner());


//calculating values 

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    //calculate();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show(); 
}
```

But if I click edittext a second time I get the following errors:

```
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6116)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.widget.TextView.access$700(TextView.java:187)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.beforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextWillChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:878)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:279)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:384)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:292)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-25 16:23:05.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove Textchangelistener

> txt[i].removeTextChangedListener(watcher);

Answer (score 16):

Instead of implementing **`EditTextTouchLisner`**, you can implement **`addTextChangedListener`** to your EditText.

addTextChangedListener takes [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) object as an argument

Here is a [Help With TextWatcher](http://marakana.com/forums/android/learning_android_book/487.html)

Comment: i did same thing (see the second segment of code)...if i intially add the addTextChangedListener then the all texts chngelistner will overlap one another no?.. wht u say?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: I was to answer the same as you did,but I too didn't figure out,how would he be able to know which 'EditText' is being changed..

Comment: @ Hiral Yes that is important..Im achieving it by click event

Answer (score 0):

What about storing EditText with focus and, inside the change listener, performs operation only if the view that generated the change event is equal to the one who got the focus?

Doing this, no need to attach, detach and reattach listener.

Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but in my case there was a different cause:

I added the textChangedListener to my EditText before I initialized the TextChangedListener

so I had this:

```
filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
filterTextWatcher = new NavigationTextWatcher(adapter);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

instead of:

```
filterTextWatcher = new NavigationTextWatcher(adapter);
filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```